# GWT localized generated Messages

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I basically have following configuration. 
My `app.gwt.xml` contains the following modules and settings

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="en_US, de_DE, default"/>
<set-property name="locale" value="default"/>
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en_US"/>

<!--  Localization -->

<generate-with class="app.com.gen.MyGenerator">
    <when-type-assignable class="app.com.msg.IMessages" />
</generate-with>
```

My Generator is generating a HashMap per locale depending on the available locales.
I am using `GWT.create(MyMessages.class)`. MyMessages implements the interface `app.com.msg.IMessages`.

So right now at compile time I have 3 Permutations, what is fine. 
When I run my example, I only get to see the page with the default locale, doesnt matter
if I am changing the URL parameter to &locale=de_DE or whatever.

I also have added the parameter

```
<head>
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=en_US">
</head>
```

to my HTML file.

In DevMode it works, because the generated MyMessages class is compiled on the fly, but not when I run the compiled version.
Any advices? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with this config:

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en_US, de_DE"/>
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en_US"/>
<set-property name="locale" value="en_US, de_DE"/>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, guess I just had some issues to initialize a locale parameter at login time for the url. The Mapping was working fine.